# In Windows Workflow (WF), how is the concept of a "work item" expressed?

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Years ago (before WF existed) I worked on a custom workflow engine. It worked like this: Design a workflow (known as the definition), associate a specific type of work item with that definition (e.g.: Workflow Definition X processes Widgets), and process that work item through it's various states and transitions by creating one instance of that definition per work item.

The work item implemented an IWorkItem interface, which allowed it to be processed as a kind of state machine (for example, it had a current state and a set of methods such as Run, Stop, Pause, etc. to control it).

In Windows Workflow, how do you define a work item? Can it be a custom entity modeled in my SQL Server database? Do I have to give it any particular fields? Does the object that represents it in my code have to implement particular interfaces? How does it respond to persistance/de-persistance in terms of the underlying row data? How can I easily query the database to get my entity's state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work item in WF is the workflow itself, which is composed of "activities" (which can be built-in or custom made by deriving from one of the .net activity types. There are extensions that can be added in that support persistence, tracing, etc. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee342461.aspx) is a good intro on the framework.

In my personal experience, I read a book because at the time, the MSFT docs weren't great for WF4, but it looks better now. I've been able to get a workflow going that models the sales process put in place at my office. The sales people use a Silverlight client that connects to a WCF service which in turns serves data stored in my persistence tables. It also interacts with a Workflow Service that manages creting new instances of the workflow and persisting existing instances back to the SQL db. As far as querying existing instances, this is pretty simple. In my case, I installed the instance store database that MSFT provides, and I simply query one of the tables they provide.

Comment: Let's assume that the item being processed in the workflow is a gallon of milk. I've got a milk table, with properties like carton_type, milk_id, exp_date, etc. I want to track the progress of a certain gallon over time. It could have possible states such as expired, consumed, etc. Could you give me a little info on how I'd track this object/row over time using a workflow?

Comment: You'll want to read about workflow persistence, more specifically, how you can promote properties. Using your example, assuming you've already installed the supplied persistence database, you could promote properties of your gallon of milk which you could query in the System.Activities.DurableInstancing.InstancePromotedProperties view in SQL. You could write a query to only return milk which will expire in 2 days, assuming you've promote the gallon's expiration date. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee364726(VS.100).aspx) site should be helpful to you